# Policies folder in WinSxS in Windows 7

Tags: c++

I am trying to run a native application that was built using Visual Studio 2008 in Windows 7. I have installed Visual Studio 2008 on the new machine. I get an error saying that the side-by-side configuration is incorrect. So I copied the needed redistributable files and manifests from the old system(Windows XP) to my new machine(Windows 7) at the same location. But still I am not able to run the application. I am actually not able to find a folder called 'Policies' that was present in Windows XP's WinSxS folder. Where can I find this folder and how can I run the application?

Thanks,
Rakesh.

Answer (score 0):

All visual studio versions have a matching redistributable package. This is an executable which when run will set up the SxS folder as needed. You're best off treating this as magic.

<sup>I think SxS is one of the worst ideas Microsoft ever had in Win32 development</sup>

Comment: Looks like magic to me too. Seriously, this has to have some solution.